# How to make a DateTime from a string?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

```
string line = "";
line = Console.ReadLine(); //for e.g : 20 10 10 200 (20 hours, 10 minutes, 10 seconds, 200 milliseconds)

DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(line, "HH mm ss fff",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

So there I'm trying to create a DateTime from a string, but it's not really working.

Comment: What is not working?  Also, I do not see an array here at all

Comment: Can you include example input and the exception that it raised?

Comment: Please put a breakpoint on the last line of code. Run to it. Go to the `Immediate Window`. Type in `?line`. What is shown as the result?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry from a string. Just first when I typed in the question I tried to use an array

Comment: What kind of `DateTime` would you expect from this, though? Hours, minutes and seconds only specify a time. It would parse just fine as a `TimeSpan` if the format string was `@"hh\ mm\ ss\ fff"`. Alternatively, you may want to parse some integers instead and then invoke the `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` constructor that takes the relevant parts as arguments.

Comment: I want to get: Hours, mintues, seconds and milliseconds.

Comment: @PéterKiss I think you forgot to respond to my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to work correctly when I put it in this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mG8BCF and use the exact input that you include in your comment.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var line = Console.ReadLine(); //for e.g : 20 10 10 200 (20 hours, 10 minutes, 10 seconds, 200 milliseconds)
        DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(line, "HH mm ss fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);        
        Console.WriteLine(time);
    }
}
```

> 11/27/2018 8:10:10 PM